# What is a good C or Obj-C framework for manipulating Git Repositories?

Tags: c, libraries, objective-c

What Obj-C/C libraries have you used for manipulating git repos in your Mac apps?

I am working on a Mac app that I would like to be able to clone and modify git repos. Using git directly is not an option as it is GPL and I'd like to sell my app commercially without opening the source. I've seen libgit2, which I could link, but I'm not sure how to do that properly, and it doesn't appear to implement any of the things necessary for pushing/pulling repos over the git protocol.

Comment: I have a feeling that http://stackoverflow.com would be more effective place to ask

Comment: What can your app do that isn't available with the existing offerings?

Comment: @Thorbjørn - it's utilizing a git repo as a data store, it has nothing to do with "managing" a git repo like GitX (and others) do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

libgit2 is the only existing Git library that can be linked with a proprietary application without opening its source. Unfortunately, the Git network protocol hasn't been implemented yet -- but it is on the works and the development is moving quite fast.

I think your best bet would be waiting ~1 month until the network support is ready, or switching to Java and using JGit. There are no other options when developing with Obj-C.

Comment: Thanks, an alternative for mac development is to embed MacRuby and embed something like the Grit gem.